# Red-black tree trinode restructuring after insertion and deletion

Tags: data-structures, proof-techniques, search-trees, red-black-trees

When performing an insertion/deletion on a red-black tree, how can be argued or proved that it requires at most one/two trinode restructuring(s) respectively?
My thoughts so far were: after inserting a node and two consecutive red nodes exist along a path from root to a leaf a restructuring is done followed by recoloring, resulting in a red-black tree. Does this mean that after inserting a node there can only exist at most one double red problem in the tree which requires one restructuring to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/109232/proofs-for-red-black-tree-insertion-and-deletion?noredirect=1#comment233471_109232

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3221497/14578